# Azure CLI returns an incomplete list of webapps

Tags: azure-cli

I have been building applications that run on Azure using the Portal and Visual Studio for several years, and I am very happy with it, but after seeing Scott Gutherie demo the command line tools, I decided to give it a go.

When I try to get a list of my web apps, the list is incomplete. `az webapp list` returns data on one of the two App Service apps that I have in my account, but the other is conspicuously missing, and I haven't been able to sort out why.

Both apps appear in the Azure Portal.

The two apps run in different locations (East US and East US 2), and they belong to different resource groups. Those are the only difference that I can think of. Both were created by deploying an ASP.NET MVC app from within Visual Studio.

Any ideas? Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: If you execute `az webapp list -n <name> -g <rgname>`, what is the result?

Comment: The two webapps are created by Visual Studio or one is created by Visual Studio and one is create on Portal, app created by VS you could not list it?

Comment: I know for sure that the app that is not listed was created through Visual Studio. I can't recall how I created the one that is listed; it was done a long time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a known issue. I test in my lab, I get the same result with you. Following is my test steps.

1. Publish a web app to Azure new resource group from Visual Studio.
2. Use `az webapp list` check, I could not find the webapp I publish. Only could find web app created on Azure Portal.
3. Use `az web list -g shuivs`. the result is null.
   C:\Users\v-shshui>az webapp list -g shuivs
   []
4. Use `az webapp show -n <name> -g <rgname>`, I get the following error.
   C:\Users\v-shshui>az webapp show -n "WebSite1120171130022504" -g "shuivs"
   Usage Error: WebSite1120171130022504 is not a correct app type
5. I find webapp publish from Visual Studio have different web app kind with created on Portal. I use Power Shell to check it.

[image]

According to my test, Azure Cli 2.0 list web app according to web app attribute ‘Kind’. Azure Cli 2.0 can not list web app published from Visual Studio.

Comment: I had give a feedback to Azure, you will give a feedback to Azure. Hope it helps.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I will report the issue to Azure.

Comment: @AdamCrossland I test in my lab. Azure Power Shell does not have this issue.